# How to remove first 3 characters of every selected song title in iTunes?

Tags: windows, itunes

How can I remove the first 3 characters of every selected song title in iTunes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [Teridon's iTunes Scripts](http://mysite.verizon.net/teridon/itunesscripts/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

You might also be able to use something like [Mp3tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/).  Obviously this would be outside of iTunes, but it might accomplish what you want.